# when i try to upgrade flutter by using "flutter upgrade" i get the following error

Tags: flutter

ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:

```
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: Unknown error code (err 8)
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
  Command: git fetch --tags
```

I ran flutter doctor and there is no error

Comment: flutter doctor -v shows no errors with remote servers?  And do you have an up to date git?  And have you used your distro already successfully, and this is now just an upgrade?

Comment: Which OS are you using. Try reinstalling flutter.